# When did Jesus enter Jerusalem? Passover or Sukkot?

Tags: jesus, new-testament, passover

According to gospel of john and gospel of mark, Jesus entered Jerusalem a week before Passover. But the crowds were shouting "Hosanna" and waving with leafy palm tree leaves while jesus rode on the donkey. It is dubious since many elements here are part of sukkot tradition rather than that of the passover.  By the way, I am curious about the habit of growth of fig tree and palm trees in middle east.

> 11 As they approached Jerusalem and came to Bethphage and Bethany at
>   the Mount of Olives, Jesus sent two of his disciples, 2 saying to
>   them, “Go to the village ahead of you, and just as you enter it, you
>   will find a colt tied there, which no one has ever ridden. Untie it
>   and bring it here. 3 If anyone asks you, ‘Why are you doing this?’
>   say, ‘The Lord needs it and will send it back here shortly.’” 4 They
>   went and found a colt outside in the street, tied at a doorway. As
>   they untied it, 5 some people standing there asked, “What are you
>   doing, untying that colt?” 6 They answered as Jesus had told them to,
>   and the people let them go. 7 When they brought the colt to Jesus and
>   threw their cloaks over it, he sat on it. 8 Many people spread their
>   cloaks on the road, while others spread branches they had cut in the
>   fields. 9 Those who went ahead and those who followed shouted,
>   “Hosanna![a]” “Blessed is he who comes in the name of the Lord!”[b]
>   10 “Blessed is the coming kingdom of our father David!” “Hosanna in
>   the highest heaven!” 11 Jesus entered Jerusalem and went into the
>   temple courts. He looked around at everything, but since it was
>   already late, he went out to Bethany with the Twelve.*
>
> 12 The next day the great crowd that had come for the festival heard
>   that Jesus was on his way to Jerusalem. 13 They took palm branches and
>   went out to meet him, shouting, “Hosanna![a]” “Blessed is he who comes
>   in the name of the Lord!”[b] “Blessed is the king of Israel!” 14 Jesus
>   found a young donkey and sat on it, as it is written: 15 “Do not be
>   afraid, Daughter Zion;
>       see, your king is coming,
>       seated on a donkey’s colt.”[c] 16 At first his disciples did not understand all this. Only after Jesus was glorified did they realize
>   that these things had been written about him and that these things had
>   been done to him. 17 Now the crowd that was with him when he called
>   Lazarus from the tomb and raised him from the dead continued to spread
>   the word. 18 Many people, because they had heard that he had performed
>   this sign, went out to meet him. 19 So the Pharisees said to one
>   another, “See, this is getting us nowhere. Look how the whole world
>   has gone after him!”**

Comment: If the figs were ready by summer(Matthew 24:32), then if it were the latter it would seem there would have been some figs around by the seventh month.

Answer (score 1):

There can be no doubt that Jesus entered Jerusalem in the days before the Passover festival as it is specifically mentioned by all evangelists: Matt 26:17, Mark 14:12, Luke 22:7, John 13:1.

Palm branches were used as a symbol (in this instance) of the entrance of a triumphal king and the Jerusalem crowds celebrated Jesus' entry as such, John 19:19.  This is a similar practice as recorded elsewhere such as 1 Macc 13:51, 2 Macc 10:7.  Many modern Christian churches still commemorate this on "Palm Sunday".

Palm branches were also used at the feast of tabernacles to remind the people that the Israelites were brought out of Egypt and had to once live in "booths" or tents or temporary houses.  They usually constructed such temporary dwellings on the rooves of their houses and lived in them during the feast of tabernacles (hence its name).  Lev 23:42, 43.  Thus, Palm branches served a dual function - for a triumphant king and the feast of tabernacles.